# Matlab debugger show variables after crash

Tags: matlab, debugging

I have a code with lots of variables during run and it crashes on a certain line. Now, obviously I want to use the debugger to show explicitly the variable values at crash. However, I can define a breakpoint on that line, but when I click 'continue' enough times for the code to crash (the line is inside a loop, and crashes on the last run of the loop), matlab clears the workspace of all the run-time variables.

Do you know how to maintain the variables to see the values which cause the crash? Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `dbstop if error` then matlab will stop at the line that causes the error, before it actually causes a crash, keeping all the defined variables in the current (function's) workspace.

Another method is error handling using `try`-`catch ME`, but that seems overkill in your situation.

Comment: Another option is to just use a conditional break point. Set the condition to be some state that indicates its the last loop iteration (easy with a for loop)

Comment: `dbstop if error` indeed seems to be the way to go. Note that if an extensive analysis is required you can use the `save` command to store your variables from debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

If the crash occurs in the last routine, so run the loop for one less time, and you have all of your variables, so you can also save them if you want.
Now you can run line-by-line, inside the loop.